# Feature Importance from OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As the title suggests, how can I obtain the feature importances from a `OneVsRestClassifier` model?

I tried using `model.feature_importances_` but the error message was

> "OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_"

Tried searching from the internet but was not able to find any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneVsRestClassifier()` basically builds as much binary classifiers as there are classes. Each has its own set of importances (assuming the base classifier supports them), showing the importance of features to distinguish a certain class from all others when generalizing on the train set. Those can be accessed with `.estimators_[i].feature_importances_`.

Alternatively, you may study other sorts of feature importances, like `sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance`, which are universally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to get important features for a stacked classification with sklearn below. Here the stacked_model is the model built with `OneVsRestClassifier` :

```
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
# to get permutation: 
results = permutation_importance(stacked_model, x, y, scoring='accuracy')
# get important features:
important_features = results.importances_mean
# list all features:
for i,v in enumerate(important_features):
 print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
```